# creating SVG text with javascript (in empty div)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to get some experience in manipulating
a `SVG` with `d3.js` and I'm stuck with text. Somehow I cannot change the value of the text.

Here is the code I tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FIXME</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    <link href="html5reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container">
        <div id="insertTextHere">
        </div>
 </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Just a `html` empty page with a div in it.
Here is the `script`:

```
var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width",  500)
        .attr("height", 250);
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .attr("rotate", 90)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("font-size",25)
    .node.textContent="test";
```

The Text is Empty and i cannot find a way to change the text in it. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: where is the `div` corresponidng to the `.chart` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is bit difficult to understand the question,

Assuming you want to add an `SVG` to the `div` and add a `text` node to it and change the text value.

Here is a snippet which can do it for you. working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kq8okc4h/)

```
<div class="chart">
</div>

<script>
var svg = d3.select('.chart')
.append('svg')
.attr({
 width : 300,
 height: 300,
})
.style('background-color' ,'green')
;

svg.append('text')
.attr({
x: 20,
y: 30
})
.text('Hello World')
;
</script>
```